# Facebook Messenger Bot: Detect refocus on conversation?

Tags: bots, facebook-messenger, messenger, botframework, botkit

With my messenger bot, if I send a user a link, and they end up clicking the link which opens their web browser outside the Facebook Messenger App, is it possible to detect when the user has re-entered the conversation?

Is there an API call that indicates that the user is now "focused" on the chat conversation with my bot?

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to do that... however you can always send user a push message after a certain time period, to enquire/check/notify any further request/interest.

Comment: thanks for the response. i figured this was the case but wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything in the Messenger Platform that natively lets you know when a user has re-entered chat. The best you could do **natively** would be sending the user a message after they've opened the webview and listening to a message_read event on return.

But at that point you're already using the Messenger Extensions SDK to let the bot know the user has landed on the page. At that point, it is much easier to trigger a message back to your server on completion of some action within your webview.